# Java: Linked Lists

Tags: java, loops, while-loop, linked-list

So my logic and my code makes sense, but when it runs it doesn't stop and keeps on running so i guess its an error in my loop, but i am not really sure where?

```
public void triplicate(){
    Link current = head;
    while(current!=null)
    {
    Link L1 = new Link (current.data);
    Link L2 = new Link (current.data);
    current.next=L1;
    L1.next=L2;
    L2.next=current.next;
    L1.data=current.data;
    L2.data=current.data;
    current=current.next;
    }
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    LinkList l1 = new LinkList();
    l1.insertLast(6);
    l1.insertLast(3);
    l1.insertLast(9);
    System.out.println(l1);
    l1.triplicate();
    System.out.print(l1);
}
```

Hope someone could point to where my mistake is
Thanks a bunch

Comment: What is `LinkList`?  Does this code actually compile?  Please post a [mcve]

Comment: `L2.next = null; and current = current.next.next;`

Comment: @LuaiGhunim doesnt work

Comment: Because you are creating nodes inside the while loop and current will never reach a null node and your code is totally wrong , it will not save anything .

Comment: [I downvoted because you don't appear to have made any effort to debug the code](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/).

Answer (score 0):

Consider your code:

```
current.next=L1;
L1.next=L2;
L2.next=current.next;
```

This will end up with L2.next assigned L1 which will be a circular reference. I'm sure that's not what you want.

Try splitting into a couple of methods to make it a bit more obvious what you are doing. Something like:

```
private Link duplicate(Link link) {
    Link newLink = new Link(link.data);
    newLink.next = link.next;
    link.next = newLink;
    return newLink;
}

private void triplicate() {
    for (Link link = head; link != null; link = link.next)
        link = duplicate(duplicate(link));
}
```

Comment: so if i change it to L2.next=current.next.next.next .  will it work ?

Comment: @Massoud Why don't you just try it instead of asking others to do your homework?